# Javascript Error When <!DOCTYPE html> Is Added To JSP Page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have the following code snippet in JSP page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java"
import="java.util.*,java.sql.*,javax.naming.*%>
<html>
<head>
......
.......
```

When I tried to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to top of page, I am getting the following error

> Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

What could be the reason for this and how to resolve this error?

Scripts block

```
<script>
function myFunc() {
    if (prod.value.length > chars) {
        prod.value = prod.value.substring(0, chars);
        alert('Exceeded');
    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please post any `<script>` blocks you have in your page.

Comment: @Dai I have edited my question to include script block.

Comment: Where is `prod` and `chars` defined in your script? It isn't declared or retrieved from anywhere unless you have other scripts that affect the global scope too.

Comment: try using a debugger..for example in chrome u can  debug by pressing ctrl+shift+i ..Also are you doing this on IE?

Comment: @Dai It is declared as global. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` shifts the browser into Strict Mode, which means it has narrower tolerances for common coding errors in addition to having slightly different CSS behaviour.

It sounds like you have a `<script type="text/javascript">` on your page which uses an obsoleted or deprecated technique for getting input values.

I suggest using a Script Debugger (IE, Chrome, Safari and Firefox all feature script debuggers, all accessed by pressing F12) and stepping through your scripts to find the cause of the error and then fixing it yourself.

Comment: Using IE F12 debugger, I have found the following line of code is causing an issue  `if (document.getElementById("plan").value=="null" || document.getElementById("plan").value=="E" )`

Comment: @Polppan That shows that `document.getElementById("plan")` is returning null. You need to fix that.

Comment: As you have rightly pointed, when `<!DOCTYPE html>` is added, there were couple of JS errors which did not throw before. Thanks a lot for pointing this out.